# Message for unique validator is not coming in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-validation

I have following rule for email to be unique in modal

```
   [['email'], 'unique'],
```

I am **not using** ajax to submit form.
Problem is that I am getting  all rules validation messages except unique rule.

So how to make unique  rule work at client end?

What am I missing ? Please help

Comment: without ajax validation there is no way to check unique rule at client end

Comment: @СеменихинМаксим but I am not saving form with ajax .. what should I do ? Please suggest

Comment: try this one `['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\frontend\models\User', 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],`

Answer (score 3):

**The only way is to `enableAjaxValidation` at client side**

[Here is doc about it](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html)

> To enable AJAX validation for a single input field, configure the
>   enableAjaxValidation property of that field to be true and specify a
>   unique form id:

```
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'registration-form',
]);

echo $form->field($model, 'username', ['enableAjaxValidation' => true]);

// ...

ActiveForm::end();
```

> You also need to prepare the server so that it can handle the AJAX
>   validation requests. This can be achieved by a code snippet like the
>   following in the controller actions:

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return ActiveForm::validate($model);
}
```

Comment: When I add code like this .. clientside validations stop working .On submit it takes me to the server without any validation

Comment: provide full php js html code and we will help you with it

Comment: You must overwrite `clientValidateAttribute` function before use ajaxValidation.
Link: [http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#deferred-validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#deferred-validation)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this has to come from **DB's ActiveRecordSet** on an update that's when it realizes this field is unique. The easiest way is by doing a check if `($model->save())` is true otherwise return/render back the form and you will see a framework message that a particular field has been taken already.

Comment: please change your answer's format for more readable reasons.